# Error implementing child routes in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm getting below error while implementing child routes for my project. I didn't find any help on GitHub and other sites.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute
>   'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL
>   'http://%28routes%29/' cannot be created in a document with origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' and URL 'http://localhost:4200/'. Error:
>   Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object
>   with URL 'http://%28routes%29/' cannot be created in a document with
>   origin 'http://localhost:4200' and URL 'http://localhost:4200/'.

Comment: Hello, could you show us how you configured your routes ?

Comment: It will help us find your answer if you add your code implementation in your question

Comment: Try using Hash Based Routing Strategy

imports [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
]

Comment: const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
        children: [
            {path: '', component: CutoffValidationComponent},
            {path: 'CutoffValidation', component: CutoffValidationComponent},
            {path: 'routes', component: RoutesComponent},
            {path: 'cutoffs', component: CutoffsComponent}            
        ]
    },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: false });

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and it was caused by missing slash '/' in front of the router link string. To be more clear I had the problem when the link was defined as:

`<mat-list-item><a class="mat-h3 menu-link" [routerLink]="['about']">About</a></mat-list-item>`

The problem disappeared when I corrected it to:

`<mat-list-item><a class="mat-h3 menu-link" [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a></mat-list-item>`

Answer (score 1):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
        children: [
            {path: '', component: CutoffValidationComponent},
            {path: 'CutoffValidation', component: CutoffValidationComponent},
            {path: 'routes', component: RoutesComponent},
            {path: 'cutoffs', component: CutoffsComponent},
            {path: 'piece', component: PiecesComponent},
            {path: 'flights', component: FlightsComponent}

        ]
    },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: false });
```

This how I have the routes configured.